# Win 10 Home - change drive for System Volume Information

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, filesystems, 64-bit

I have several external hard drives and I wish to move a System Volume Information folder from Drive G to Drive F, however that is being prevented by system protection. Any attempt to Delete, Move or Change that folder fails to happen!!!  Is it actually possible for a user to choose where to locate such a system folder???

Comment: System Volume Information stores the volume's recovery information so it can't be moved to another volume

Answer (score 0):

Well, Each NTFS drive in Windows has system volume information folder in it.
it contains drive specific recovery information.

this folder is hidden by default  and it is not displayed in normal search.

it is unclear ,why u want to move that folder to somewhere,
if You want any content from it then you can simply copy it.

if it is big in size and you want to free space then you can use disk cleanup tool on that drive.

it is wise to not mess with this type of folder.

Answer (score 0):

You cant edit or move or rename or do any modification to it. Its system folder created by windows OS and each disk drive your system has, this folder will be created for each one of them (usually not for the removable disks). Mainly that folder has information and data and files necessary for the System Restore function.
What you need to do is if free up some space from that drive, you can use windows' built in disk clean up tool for that particular drive. in there, you can choose to delete all restore data but the last one. You can also delete junk files and history items to free up disk space.